# How to have sales of every product for each day in SSIS?

Tags: ssis

My data is pretty standard, but it's in multiple flat files, hence why I'm using SSIS. I have:

- Date
- Product ID
- Number sold
- Seller ID

I have 30 products, so for every day I'd like to have 30 line, one for each product. That way, I could see that on date X, we've sold 10 product A, 0 product B, and so forth.

I'm not sure which tool I should be using. I've tried with Aggregate, but I don't think it's the right way to do it. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the rows using `cross join` and then use `left join` to bring in the data.

Assuming your table has all the dates and all the products (although not necessarily all the combinations).  The basic idea is:

```
select d.date, p.product, coalesce(t.numsold, 0)
from (select distinct date from t) d cross join
     (select distinct product from t) p left join
     t
     on t.date = d.date and t.product = p.product;
```

Oh, I noticed that your data has a supplier id, so there are probably multiple rows for a given product on a given date.  Hence, some aggregation is needed.  Here is one way:

```
select d.date, p.product, coalesce(sum(t.numsold), 0)
from (select distinct date from t) d cross join
     (select distinct product from t) p left join
     t
     on t.date = d.date and t.product = p.product
group by d.date, p.product;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't guarantee that all dates will be in the product table, you can generate a **calendar table** in a cte (or preferably persist it to a table).

```
declare @FromDate date; 
declare @ThruDate date; 
set @FromDate = '2010-01-01';
set @ThruDate = '2020-12-31';
with x as (
  select top (cast(sqrt(datediff(day, @FromDate, @ThruDate)) as int) + 1)
      [number] 
    from [master]..spt_values v
  )
/* Date Range CTE */
,calendar as (
  select top (1+datediff(day, @FromDate, @ThruDate))
        DateValue  = convert(date,dateadd(day,
          row_number() over (order by x.number)-1,@FromDate)
          )
    from x cross join x as y
      order by DateValue
  )
  --select DateValue from calendar into dbo.calendar;
```

> From there you can adapt @GordonLinoff's answer to use the **calendar table or cte** and determine the date range in the subquery's `where` clause.

```
select [date] = cal.datevalue, p.product, NumSold= coalesce(sum(t.numsold), 0)
  from (
    select datevalue 
      from calendar 
      where datevalue >= '2016-12-01'
        and datevalue <= '2016-12-31'
        ) as cal
  cross join (
    select distinct product 
      from t
      ) as p 
  left join t on t.date = cal.datevalue and t.product = p.product
group by cal.datevalue, p.product;
```

More about calendar tables and number generation:

- Aaron Bertrand - Generate a set or sequence without loops

  - [generate-a-set-1](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)
  - [generate-a-set-2](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)
  - [generate-a-set-3](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3)
- [David Stein - Creating a Date Table/Dimension on SQL 2008](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/06/creating-a-date-tabledimension-for-sql-server-2008/)
- [Michael Valentine Jones - F_TABLE_DATE](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=61519)